# Mounting ntfs subdirectories of device

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, ntfs, arch-linux

I have an external hard drive mounted in arch-linux using /etc/fstab:

```
dev/sda1       /mnt/share      ntfs-3g user,users,gid=users,fmask=113,dmask=002,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0


charles@arch ~ $ ls -l /mnt/share
total 13
drwxrwxr-x 1 root users 4096 Jan  5 03:20 Audio
drwxrwxr-x 1 root users 4096 Jan  5 09:07 Photos
drwxrwxr-x 1 root users    0 Jan  4 10:58 $RECYCLE.BIN
drwxrwxr-x 1 root users 4096 Jan  5 09:21 Videos
```

All directores are owned by `root:users` and I can't change ownership, nor create a subdirectory with different ownership (as it's ntfs).

Let's suppuse the hard disk has subdirectories `hdd_subdir_1` and `hdd_subdir_2`, both top-level. In addition, I have `root` user and `unpriv`, a completely unproviliged user on linux.

I wish to mount the device with 2 mountpoints:

1. /mnt/share/subdir_1 as mount point as above, pointing to `hdd_subdir_1` on device;
2. /mnt/share/subdir_2 as mount point, where `/mnt/share/subdir2` is owned by `unpriv:unpriv`, pointing to `hdd_subdir_2` on device.

So 2 different default privileges, 2 mount points, 1 device. How do I do this? If not for the different privileges, I'd just set up symlinks or use `mount -bind`. But I can't make it work for the use case above. Thanks!

Comment: Try mounting your ntfs partiton with the permissions option. `users,permissions,locale=en_US.UTF-8` You can then chown/chmod the direcotires.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: This does not work; the behavior is the same. I can only `mkdir` as root and cannot change ownership in `/mnt/share`.

Comment: OK, then you will have to use ext4 (or other linux native)

Comment: I need to share it with Windows, so I can't use ext4.

Comment: use one of the windows drivers - http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/ or make more then one partition on the device.

Comment: I will try the change on the Windows side. Thanks. In the meantime - is there any fix (way to vary permissions on different mounts of same device) retaining ntfs/ntfs-3g?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to accomplish the setup above now, by a combination of local settings and `/etc/fstab` settings.

Comment: I have a similar problem, so it would be nice to see more details about how you achieved it.